# Getting Error"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Contract.GitCheckOutConflictException" while changing the GIT Repo in vs 2019

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, git-clone

I have a repo with one solution in X branch. I removed it from my local machine and copied another repo in Y branch to the same location. I tried to open the new repo from the X branch. It opened and pointed to Y location automatically. I restarted the vs2019 and opened the X branch from azure devops which is already pushed. But unable to pull the code. So I tried to switch to main branch and I got this error. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Repo has branches vice verca is not true

Comment: Just try to stash and then pull

Comment: Thanks very much @viveknuna I was able to resolve this now

Comment: flat that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue when I completely removed the repo from disk and recloned. This is an issue that needs to get resolved though. My fix should only be considered a workaround. ([this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-of-type-microsoftteamfoundationgitcontra-1/1433369))
Also I think you have some conflict .
Check for conflict .

** Also you can try this way :
Stash and commit the pull and push

Comment: dang that didnt work for me